# Fixed columns with colored header in DT datatable

Tags: javascript, r, datatables, dt

I am trying to generate a `DT::datatable` with fixed columns and a colored header. This is my code:

```
library(dplyr)

mtcars %>%
  DT::datatable(
    extensions = c("FixedColumns"),
    options = list(
      fixedColumns = list(leftColumns = 2),
      paging = FALSE,
      scrollX = TRUE,
      scrollY = "400px",
      initComplete = DT::JS(
        "function(settings, json) {",
        "$(this.api().table().header()).css({'background-color': 'red'});",
        "}")
    )
  )
```

Unfortunately the fixed header part does not get colored while the moving part of the header gets red (as expected). I am not good at JS so maybe the error lies in the JS insertion above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works with the `headerCallback` option:

```r
library(DT)

js <- c(
  "function(thead, data, start, end, display) {",
  "  $('th', thead).css('background-color', 'red');",
  "}"
)

datatable(
  mtcars,
  extensions = c("FixedColumns"),
  options = list(
    fixedColumns = list(leftColumns = 2),
    paging = FALSE,
    scrollX = TRUE,
    scrollY = "400px",
    headerCallback = JS(js)
  )
)
```

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks @Stéphane Laurent. Maybe you can also answer my [follow up question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77906688/fixed-columns-with-striped-rows-in-dt-datatable) for striped rows? Would be very kind.