# Fixed columns with striped rows in DT datatable

Tags: javascript, r, datatables, dt

I am trying to generate a DT::datatable with fixed columns and striped rows. This is my code:

```
library(DT)

rowCallback <- paste0(
    "function(row, data, num, index){",
    "  var $row = $(row);",
    "  if($row.hasClass('even')){",
    "    $row.css('background-color', 'white');",
    "  }else{",
    "    $row.css('background-color', 'blue');",
    "  }",
    "}"
  )

datatable(
  mtcars,
  extensions = c("FixedColumns"),
  options = list(
    fixedColumns = list(leftColumns = 2),
    paging = FALSE,
    scrollX = TRUE,
    scrollY = "400px",
    rowCallback = DT::JS(rowCallback)
  )
)
```

Unfortunately the fixed row part does not get striped while the moving part of the rows gets blue (as expected). I am not good at JS so maybe the error lies in the JS insertion above? This is kind of a follow up question to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77901109/fixed-columns-with-colored-header-in-dt-datatable) answered question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you set a style for the `row` which gets inherited by or passed to all child nodes which don't have a style attribute. However, the fixed columns already have a `style` attribute and hence do not inherit the style set for the row. One option to fix that would be to set the style for the child nodes.

```
library(DT)

rowCallback <- paste0(
  "function(row, data, num, index){",
  "  var $row = $(row);",
  "  if($row.hasClass('even')){",
  "    $row.children().css('background-color', 'white');",
  "  }else{",
  "    $row.children().css('background-color', 'blue');",
  "  }",
  "}"
)

datatable(
  mtcars,
  extensions = c("FixedColumns"),
  options = list(
    fixedColumns = list(leftColumns = 2),
    paging = FALSE,
    scrollX = TRUE,
    scrollY = "400px",
    rowCallback = DT::JS(rowCallback)
  )
)
```

Comment: Works perfectly! Thanks a lot (also for the explanation)